# Call UI screen not coming on OnePlus devices

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, lockscreen, incoming-call

I am working on an application where i am using an Activity over the default device lockscreen and when there is an incoming call i am using a broadcast receiver to receive that event and then i am finishing my activity, after which the default incoming call UI screen comes up, which is the default behaviour and it should be the perfect solution, but in my case, this scenario is working completely fine on all devices except that on OnePlus devices.

What happening on OnePlus devices is, for the first time till the activity has been closed once, the call ui screen is not coming and there is defalult lockscreen and user can only see a call icon in notification.

Broadcast receiver code that i am using:

```
class IncomingCallReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            callStatus = intent.getStringExtra("call_event");
        }
        finish();

    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me why this is happening.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue,